# Android apps on grandstream phones

Tags: android

I have developed an Android app for my company. I have tried to install my app    in a grandstream voip phone its installed but not opening. Phone has hanged. Nothing was happening. Finally I saw on a website that told to include a jar file

Please give some suggestions I need my app has to run on a grandstream phone. Instead of android.jar I did not get that jar file and out put.

Comment: how to set compatible with grandstream mobiles in android

Comment: how to use my app in grandstream phone ..please give suggestions..